# Type The annotation @ResponsePayload is disallowed for this location

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, soap

I had make a endpoint to my SOAP application and when a make this:

```
@ResponsePayload
public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@ResponsePayload GetCountryRequest request) {
    GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
    response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName()));
}
```

This second @ResponsePayload in the method getCountry give me this error:

> The annotation @ResponsePayload is disallowed for this location

Comment: it's a `response` annotation and should not be used with `request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **[ResponsePayload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/annotation/ResponsePayload.html)** doc we can find below:

> Annotation which indicates that a method return value should be bound
>   to the response payload. Supported for annotated endpoint methods.

SO using `@RequestPayload` instead of `@ResponsePayload`

```
@ResponsePayload
public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
    GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
    response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName()));
}
```

More details can be found at **[ResponsePayload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/annotation/ResponsePayload.html)** and **[RequestPayload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/annotation/RequestPayload.html)**